# using a string variable to control a textbox property

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have various textboxes on a form to enter numbers and want to have a single function which can check the entry and highight the box in red if incorrect rather than repeating the same code for each textbox.

Is it possible to set the name of the textbox (_FreqTextBox) as a variable so I can make this a generic function for each textbox. An example function is below. I've tried to find examples of this but no luck so far. Newish to Python so apologies if this is obvious.

```
def FreqTextBoxTextChanged(self, sender, e):
    self._FreqTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    IsNumber,text_value = self.CheckNumber(self._FreqTextBox.Text)
    if (IsNumber == False):
        self._FreqTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        return
    IsNumber = self.NegativeValueMsg(text_value)
    if (IsNumber == True):
        self._FreqTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    return
```

Comment: Use [Jinja template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org) or better off Flask microgram work which has [WTForms](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/wtforms/) with form validation built-in.

Comment: Thanks for that but for the question above, is it possible to achieve without installing new addons etc.

Comment: Everything is possible. But the question is why you want to reinvent the wheel while there are many solutions available? why you are writing something that can be easily done at the client side (with JS and a little bit of css)? BTW, if you are new to Python, I would suggest you read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).